# Implement spam-block into contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contacts

I am currently looking into adding a bit of code into both the front end and back end of my form, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do so.

This is the front end code

```
<li id="user"> <label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text" name="username"> </li>
```

I will display none that and use it as a honeypot for spam bots.

However, the next bit of code I need to implement is:

```
<?php if( !isset($_POST['name'])) { die("No Direct Access"); } // Make sure the form has actually been submitted 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$spam = $_POST['username']; // This is our Honeypot field if($spam) { // If the Honeypot field has been filled in die("No spamming allowed bitch!"); } 
else { // Process the form like normal } ?>
```

Now the point being is $name and $email are dynamic fields in contact form 7. What could I do to make those avail in contact form 7 as var for this script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Inside of /contact-form-7/includes/classes.php you can add your code and mark it as spam if you want.

Line 432 under function spam() add lines that follow something similar to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $spam = true;
}
```